# Supposed to be empty return string in GAE Datastore query but falling into logic that says it found something?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In my python server side code, I run a query (q) to check if data exist for specified filter criteria.  The Name_Table in my datastore is empty so why does it fall into the if q: logic when I'm expecting it to fall into the else: logic ---- since it's an empty table entity???

```
q = Name_Table.all().filter("name =", cname).filter("provider =",refkey).filter("platform_provider =",refkey2)
```

if q: 
  xxxxx

else:
  YYYYYY

Answer (score 1):

You haven't executed the query, so you're checking that the query exists, rather than whether the query returns some data. You probably want to add `fetch(10)` or `get()` to execute the query.